# Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixBootstrapperApplication:WixNetFxExtension' in section 'Bundle:...'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, wix, wix3.10

I am trying to create a wix bootstrapper configuration.

My Bundle.wxs:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Name="..." Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="..." UpgradeCode="...">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseFile="mtel-eula-free.rtf"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixNetFxExtension" />
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload
        Name="BootstrapperCore.config"
        SourceFile="$(var.TargetDir)\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
      <Payload
        SourceFile="$(var.TargetPath)"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx452Web"/>
      <MsiPackage Id="MTESetup" SourceFile="$(var.MTESetup.TargetPath)"/>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Error:

```
Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixBootstrapperApplication:WixNetFxExtension' in section 'Bundle:...'
```

I have already added WixNetFxExtension as a reference in my bootstrapper project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixNetFxExtension" />
```

`WixNetFxExtension` is the name of a WiX extension, not a `BootstrapperApplication`. You can have only one `BootstrapperApplication` or `BootstrapperApplicationRef` per bundle.